# How do I configure a NULL object in Spring.Net

Tags: spring.net

In the particular project in which I'm working it is appropriate to to have a null log service object. Since this is configured in Spring.Net How do I configure my spring.net object to be null. This is what I'd like to do. Is it possible?

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <!-- Messages -->

  <object id ="LogService">
    <null />
  </object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject a null object :

```
<object id="MyObject">
  <property name="LogServer">
    <null/>
  </property>
</object>
```

To create a null object, you have to implement IFactoryObject and return null.
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-extension

- Bruno

Comment: Yep, this might be the easiest way to achieve what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @bbaia, I did a small test and an `IFactoryObject` that returns null is results in an `FactoryObjectNotInitializedException` thrown by the container. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9295326/322283 for details if your interested.